# How to change date format from dd MMMM YYYY in swift?

Tags: swift, dateformatter

I need date to be convert from dd MMMM YYYY to dd-mm-yyyy.

e.g. : (01 August 2021) -> 01-09-2021

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
print( dateFormatter.date(from:response.data?[0].mbStartDate ?? ""))
```

The output is nil.

I've make sure that response data value is exist

How to convert it ?

And How to change "01 August 2021" to other languange? My case is change it to indonesian. So it becomes "01 Agustus 2021". How to do this too?

Thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DateFormatter` is right way to do. First you need to convert the `01 August 2021` , `String` type, to `Date` object. Second, change `dateFormat` and re-format it. Here is tested code for both of your need:

```
func convert(_ dateString: String, from initialFormat: String, to targetFormat: String? = nil, _ locale: Locale? = nil) -> String? {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = initialFormat
    guard let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) else { return nil }
    
    if let newFormat = targetFormat {
        formatter.dateFormat = targetFormat
    }
    formatter.locale = locale
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}

print(convert("01 August 2021", from: "dd MMMM yyyy", .init(identifier: "id_ID")))
print(convert("01 August 2021", from: "dd MMMM yyyy", to: "dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

Comment: Can you make a little changes of the return? because i need it return as date
Try to directly "return date" but the output is minus 1 day from what is should be

Comment: i add this and it works "formatter.timeZone   = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")"